# How to save countup timer upon browser refresh?

Tags: javascript

I am new to stack overflow and javascript. My first task was to create a count up timer. My code works, but if the browser is refreshed I lose the timer spot. I've been reading on using local storage to save the spot, but I am not sure on how to add that into my current code. Anyone willing to lend a hand on this? This is what my current javascript looks like in my html file.

```
     window.onload = () => {
        let day = 0;
        let hour = 0;
        let minute = 0;
        let seconds = 0;
        let totalSeconds = 0;

        let intervalId = null; 

        function startTimer() {
            ++totalSeconds;
            day = Math.floor(totalSeconds/86400);
            hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds /3600);
            minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour*3600)/60);
            seconds = totalSeconds - (hour*3600 + minute*60);

            document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day;
            document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hour;
            document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minute;
            document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
        } 

        document.getElementById('start-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
            intervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
        })

        document.getElementById('stop-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (intervalId)
                clearInterval(intervalId);
        });


        document.getElementById('reset-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
            totalSeconds = 0;
            document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = '0';
            document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
            document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
            document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = '0';
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: *"I've been reading on using local storage"* - That's how I'd do it.  Have you tried?  What didn't work?  Basically you just need to store a value whenever you change it, and read the value when the page loads.

Comment: You should save the **start** timestamp, and not the counter, if you want accuracy. You can calculate the seconds elapsed with `(Date.now() - startTimestamp) / 1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, instead of storing the seconds elapsed, you should store when the timer started and then calculate the seconds elapsed.

Here, if the value for `"start-timestamp"` is present in the Local Storage, `startTimestamp` is set to it and the timer is activated.

When the timer is started, `startTimestamp` is set to the current time and stored in the Local Storage, and when it's stopped, `"start-timestamp"` is removed from the Local Storage.

```
let day = 0;
let hour = 0;
let minute = 0;
let seconds = 0;
let startTimestamp = 0;

let intervalId = null; 

function updateTimer() {
    let totalSeconds = (Date.now() - startTimestamp) / 1000;
    day = Math.floor(totalSeconds/86400);
    hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds /3600);
    minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour*3600)/60);
    seconds = totalSeconds - (hour*3600 + minute*60);

    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = day;
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hour;
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minute;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
}

{
    const _startTimestamp = localStorage.getItem("start-timestamp");
    if (_startTimestamp) {
        startTimestamp = Number(_startTimestamp);
        intervalId = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
    }
}

document.getElementById('start-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!intervalId) {
      startTimestamp = Date.now();
      localStorage.setItem("start-timestamp", startTimestamp);
      intervalId = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
  }
})

document.getElementById('stop-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (intervalId) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        localStorage.removeItem("start-timestamp");
    }
});


document.getElementById('reset-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    totalSeconds = 0;
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = '0';
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This should get me what I need or lead me down that path. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For sessionStorage try the following to check if totalSeconds already set and a valid number .. set totalSeconds to what is stored in sessionStorage otherwise set to 0:

```
  let tmpSession = parseInt(sessionStorage["totalSeconds"] ?? 0);
  let totalSeconds = (isFinite(tmpSession))? tmpSession : 0;
```

Then in startTimer() after incrementing totalseconds  write the value to sessionStorage, like so :

```
    sessionStorage.setItem("totalSeconds",totalSeconds);
```

Comment: This is a dangerous approach. Most browsers pause timers in tabs without focus.

Comment: You are correct most browser will pause times when not in focus and while I agree with you if the use case is an accurate time from moment start button was pushed then I would use a solution like the one you described above is the way to go.  However, if you want to monitor viewing time or how many times the interval has triggered (while being viewed) while running (after start button was press) then there is a solution for that too. Therefore it all comes down to what the use case and what you want to count for the solution.